# java - how to efficiently categorize user input

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a simple program that reads the user inputted integer and categorizes it based on the value until the counter reaches 70.

**Code:**

```
int counter = 0;
    int value;
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int i = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (counter != 70) {
        value = scan.nextInt();
        if (value >= 45 && value <= 55) {
            a++;
            counter++;
        } else if (value >= 56 && value <= 66) {
            b++;
            counter++;
        } else if (value >= 67 && value <= 77) {
            c++;
            counter++;
        } else if (value >= 78 && value <= 88) {
            d++;
            counter++;
        } else if (value >= 89 && value <= 99) {
            e++;
            counter++;
        } else if (value >= 100 && value <= 110) {
            i++;
            counter++;
        } else {

        }
    }

    System.out.println(a + "-" + b + "-" + c + "-" + d + "-" + e + "-" + i);
```

Obviously, this code is inefficient and I know for a fact that there are less time consuming ways to replicate this. I feel pretty dumb right now so please tell me the most efficient way.

Comment: What do you mean by *efficient*? Easier to read? Less CPU time? Less memory usage?

Comment: why do you feel this code is inefficient?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear, the fact that I put each specific conditional in separate if and else ifs felt as if this was something I could solve with brute force.

Comment: If your ranges were not always increasing `45~` `56~` `67~` then you could have had logic using `/` and a switch/case - but not so easy for your ranges.  i.e. easy for `switch (val / 10) case 4...case 10`

Answer (score 2):

Also if doing a certain number of time, the I feel a for loop is clearer.

consider using an array of ints rather than a-i

```
        int [] values = new int [6];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 70; counter++)
        {
            int value = scan.nextInt();
            if (value >= 45 && value <= 55) {
                values[0]++;
            } else if (value >= 56 && value <= 66) {
                values[1]++;
            } else if (value >= 67 && value <= 77) {
                values[2]++;
            } else if (value >= 78 && value <= 88) {
                values[3]++;
            } else if (value >= 89 && value <= 99) {
                values[4]++;
            } else if (value >= 100 && value <= 110) {
                values[5]++;
            } else {
                counter--; // out of bounds - try again
            }
        }
```

Comment: this increases readability not efficiency as mentioned in question

Comment: @javafan Yeah, I do not feel there is anything in-efficient about the original code - do you?

Comment: truly this code is efficient in its form and its efficiency couldn't be incresed

Comment: @javafan As OP said *are less time consuming ways to replicate this* I took it as meaning the time it took to write

Comment: however using array could increase efficiency as array provide contiguous memory allocation which could be faster accessed

Comment: @javafan Yeah, that will do for me - I can sleep tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int counter = 0;
int[] a = new int[6];
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (counter < 70) {
    int value = scan.nextInt();
    if (value >= 45 && value <= 110) {
        a[(value - 45) / 11]++;
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.print(a[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; ++i)
    System.out.print("-" + a[i]);
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking how to make this program with loops so this is what I came up with:

```
int min = 45;
    int max = 55;
    int counter = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(scan.nextInt());
    }

    while (min <= 100) {
        for (int value : list) {
            if (value >= min && value <= max) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(counter + "-");
        min += 11;
        max += 11;
        counter = 0;
```

I really have no idea if this allocates memory faster or not but to me, it looks tidier although it may not be efficient.

Answer (score -1):

One way to improve readability is to change variables names:

```
a becomes from45to55
b becomes from56to66
```

You can also move repeated operations into one method:

```
public static void increment(int value, int counter) {
        value++;
        counter++;
    }
```

And use try with resources block to close `Scanner`. Full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        int value;
        int from45to55 = 0;
        int from56to66 = 0;
        int from67to77 = 0;
        int from78to88 = 0;
        int from89to99 = 0;
        int from100to110 = 0;
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            while (counter != 70) {
                value = scan.nextInt();
                if (value >= 45 && value <= 55) {
                    increment(from45to55, counter);
                } else if (value >= 56 && value <= 66) {
                    increment(from56to66, counter);
                } else if (value >= 67 && value <= 77) {
                    increment(from67to77, counter);
                } else if (value >= 78 && value <= 88) {
                    increment(from78to88, counter);
                } else if (value >= 89 && value <= 99) {
                    increment(from89to99, counter);
                } else if (value >= 100 && value <= 110) {
                    increment(from100to110, counter);
                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void increment(int value, int counter) {
        value++;
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: OK, the requirements have changed, no we can to count the above but add 65~80 - you need to change three variables names as well as the `if`'s

Comment: In this case you should be able to add ranges programmatically and include them in switch block